# managing page scroll on jquery append data

Tags: html, jquery, scroll

I have a page having certain pictures and i show around 20 pictures, kind of in 20 div vertically one after another.
after those 20, i have div, show more. clicking on show more i load further 20 and append to the first set of data, a typical solution whatever we find on many websites like loading more data only when user clicks on show more/ load more.

everything works fine for me except that once i append the next set of data page does not remain still, its scroll becomes awkward and moves to the start of first div or nearby.

my question is how do we handle scrolling in these case?

Comment: please post some code so we can define why your page scroll is messing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `element.scrollIntoView();` in javascript

Or, [jquery scrollto](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: i believe element here, in element.scrollIntoView(), is the element id I had a look at scrollTo  earlier but could not understand much from this.

Comment: none of the above actually worked. but i found a good link

    http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/

    element.scrollIntoView(); did not work exactly, i instead had to like below as suggested in the above links.

    element[0].scrollIntoView(true);

however, since ScrollTO also did not work, i suspect i might be doing something strange. however @tusar your post was helpful

Comment: i am glad it was helpful to you. if your problem is not yet solved please post a simple version of your code. that way people can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's difficult to tell without any code, but it sounds like you haven't prevented the default action of the link:

```
$("#show-more-link").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   addMoreImages();
}
```

Comment: i have not prevented the e.preventDefault(); i will try this.